# How do the tangents,derivatives,continuity,diffrentiability of a function get affected if the function is squared?

Tags: calculus, tangent-line

Please explain graphically the above changes(I imply changes in roots, derivatives at some points, continuity and differentiability at some points etc

Comment: I cannot see a question here.

Comment: I mean any function not very specific, I request you to answer my query using various functions as examples.

Answer (score 1):

Take the function $f(x) = 1$ if $x$ is rational and $-1$ if $x$ is irrational.  Then $f$ is no where differentiable or continuous, and its graph has no tangent lines anywhere.

But $f^2(x) =1 $ for all real $x$, so it's differentiable and continuous everywhere and has a tangent at every point.

Comment: Can this be shown graphically?

Comment: It's pretty easy to graph the function $y=1$ and observe its various properties.

Answer (score 0):

If y is f(x) then

$$(y^2)^{'} = 2 y y^{'}$$

The place where max/min occurs (x coordinate) is unaffected. But max / min of $y$ is itself changed as do others mentioned in title line.

Comment: The place where max/min occurs implies x coordinates, right?

Comment: Yes, x coordinate.

Comment: Hey, impressed by your answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1404664/510458                                              Please tell me which book: Higher algebra or elementary algebra.Tell the chapter too if you remember.

Comment: *Higher Algebra: A Sequel to Elementary Algebra for Schools
Henry Sinclair Hall, Samuel Ratcliffe Knight*;  In India, standard algebra text in colleges for long time.

Comment: Got it.Thankyou.